# How to separate Enterprise Logging file in EventType?

Tags: logging, enterprise-library

I have a log Mysite.log

Is possible to automatically separate in Mysite.error.log, Mysite.debug.log, Mysite.warning.log? Depending of TraceEventType?

Comment: In Log4j or Log4NET you can do this.  NOt sure about enterprise library though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do it like this:

```
        Logger.Write("Message or exception", "Catergory");
```

Where category in your case would be Errors, debug or warning.

Then in your config file for Errors:

```
<listeners>
  <add fileName="Errors.log" footer="----------------------------------------"
    header="----------------------------------------" rollFileExistsBehavior="Overwrite"
    rollInterval="None" rollSizeKB="0" timeStampPattern="yyyy-MM-dd"
    listenerDataType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.Configuration.RollingFlatFileTraceListenerData, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    traceOutputOptions="None" filter="All" type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging.TraceListeners.RollingFlatFileTraceListener, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    name="Errors" />
</listeners>


<categorySources>
  <add switchValue="All" name="Errors">
    <listeners>
      <add name="Errors" />
    </listeners>
  </add>
</categorySources>
```

You need to do this for each category

Answer (score 0):

You can implement filters for this purpose or alternatively write them using different appenders.